# how does EBean map classes to tables?

Tags: orm, mapping, ebean

How does EBean map classes to tables?

I have tables like "expense_details" and classes like model.ExpenseDetails, for example, and the classes just use the @Entity annotation without explicit mapping to a table.

Is the mapping done automatically by EBean (is it smart enough with all those "_" and CamelCase names)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is, it uses exactly rule that you described, for `SomeModel` model it looks for `some_model` table, of course you can override it ie. using `@Table` annotation like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_custom_table_name")
public class SomeModel extends Model {
...
}
```